# wordpress - post type link amigável

Tags: wordpress, link

tenho um site [www.classiplast.com.br](http://www.classiplast.com.br) esta funcionando tudo certo.

Porem estou criando uma área dentro dele onde quero ter uma pagina chamada guia de empresas e quando o usuário acessar www.classiplast.com.br/guia-de-empresas abrirá uma página aonde colocarei varias categorias .... Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Como faço para ao entrar em uma categoria o link ficar

```
classiplast.com.br/guia-empresas/nome-categoria ...
```

e dentro da categoria vão ter as empresas ai queria que o link ficasse...

```
classiplast.com.br/guia-empresas/nome-categoria/nome-empresa
```

eu criei um post type mas tudo que consegui ate agora foi deixar o link desse jeito :

```
http://www.classiplast.com.br/guia-empresas/braskem/
```

se notarem tb na pagina esta assim

```
Inicio >> Braskem
```

Mas queria que seguisse o link

```
Inicios >> guia-empresas >> categoria >> braskem
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você resolver essa questão simplesmente adicionando `guia-empresas` como uma categoria geral, e as demais (`nome-categoria`) como "filhas" desta categoria.

Isso pode ser feito na opção **Pai** da tela de Edição da Categoria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Importante saber que:

- Seu *permalink* deve conter `/%category%/`
- Você **deve** selecionar apenas a categoria Filha no seu post, do contrário, ele dará preferência à categoria Pai caso as duas sejam selecionadas.